# why is my scheduled task haveing a long delay in between

Tags: java, scala

I have a process that does some works with fixed rate:

```
val scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MigrationWorker(mytask), 1000, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

My understanding is that this should do run my task, with 50 ms in between.

While running it I observed that my tasked get periodic delays, from the log, i see it runs a bunch of tasks, then pause for about 30-60 seconds, then do more.

I wonder what can cause this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll see such behavior if the task takes longer to run than the allotted window.  The scheduler may not initiate a new one of the previous one is not complete.

The other issue might be accuracy.  I don't know if you can guarantee execution every 50 ms.

Comment: Yep, on Windows XP for example, I believe you can only resolve time withing multiples of 15ms or so. The same may be true on later versions of windows, I'm not sure.  Besides that, the javadoc for "scheduleAtFixedRate" says "If any execution of this task
     * takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions
     * may start late, but will not concurrently execute.".

Comment: seems like scheduleWithFixedDelay is the right one i should use.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement I would suggest you to use schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit) that would suit your req. the method scheduleAtFixedRate increments the delay. The first execution is after 1000 ms, then 1000+50, then 1000+ 50 *2 and so on.

Comment: Check out this link, if explain it in detail. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: so I think it says the tasks is scheduled at the following times:
1000, 1050, 1100, not that delay gets longer.